# How to take multiple inputs from the user at a same time and line in java?

Tags: java, input

Suppose there are 2 int a & b, so when we take input from the scanner we need to first take one variables value then press enter then take another value from the user.
Is there any way so that the input box for the int a & b will appear at the same time and to assign the value the user will have to press enter only one time?

Comment: yes, there are several ways to do so

Comment: Surely you don't *just* want a yes/no answer to your question, so why don't you share what you've tried so far and explain what specifically is not working? If you haven't tried anything, please research and attempt this yourself *first* and come back when you run into a problem.

Comment: @MotasimFoad What's an input box?

Comment: when we are using Dr. Java a box appears where the sc.nextInt(); is called to take the input... @immibis

Comment: @Lashane If it is possible please guide me how to do it...

Answer (score 3):

If you separate your input using whitespace and then press enter like this:

```
2 3
```

You can use `nextInt()` normally:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    a = in.nextInt();
    b = in.nextInt();
}
```

`a` will contain 2 and `b` will contain 3.

If you need to, you can place both `nextInt()` calls inside a loop, so you can read multiple lines:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int numLines = in.nextInt();
    int a, b;
    for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i++) {
        a = in.nextInt();
        b = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(a + ", " + b);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok,
in this code there will be 2 input boxes which will appear one after another but i want the both boxes to appear at the same time, so that the user can give there value at a same time and the user will need to use enter only once.

Comment: @MotasimFoad What isn't working with your attempt at this so far?

Comment: @tnw , there is nothing wring with the code. Its working perfectly. Your code is also fine. But i know how to do it in this way, i was thinking to do it another way. Where we can give more then one inputs on a same line.

Answer (score 1):

To take multiple inputs from the user from the same input line, you can ask the user to seperate the input with a comma or a white space.
In case of a white space, Anderson Vieira's answer gives the correct idea. You can use 2 successive `nextInt()` statements as in

```
System.out.println("Enter 2 nos.");
int a = sc.nextInt();
int b = sc.nextInt();
```

Also, you can specifically ask the user to seperate two nos. with a comma, take the input as a String and then seperate the two nos. using `Integer.parseInt()` command.

```
System.out.println("Enter 2 nos. seperated with a comma(,) or a semicolon(;)");
String S = sc.nextLine();
String nos[] = S.split("[, ;]");
int a = Integer.parseInt(nos[0]);
int b = Integer.parseInt(nos[1]);
```

You can ofcourse use any other character to seperate the nos.

Answer (score -1):

```
    int[] nums = new int[2];
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter 2 No.s, Space separated");
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        nums[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    for(int a : nums){
        System.out.println(a);
    }
```